# Deriving the formula for the number of distinct de Bruijn sequences

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am reading both https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence and the [original paper by Bruijin himself](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/252901.pdf)

How to derive step-by-step the formula for the number of distinct de Bruijn sequences since both links have different formulas ?

Note: [Circuits and Trees in Oriented Linear Graphs](https://sci-hub.ee/https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-4842-8_12) seems a bit too complicated, while the book chapter in [A Course in Combinatorics](https://mathematicalolympiads.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/a_course_in_combinatorics.pdf#page=87) does not do much maths proof.